# How do i validate data entered in a meta box so that only floats can be entered in a field?

Tags: plugin-development, validation

We have a custom post type in our plugin and now i must provide the user a meta box where he enters latitude and longitude. I want them to be floats, i have no problems in doing the validation client side, but i  don't know how i should handle server side validation in wordpress.

I thought that there was some API for doing this, but this is not the case, so i was just wandering how should i handle things inside my save function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not shure if this isn´t  a general php question...

Use the [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) Class.

```
// http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-float.php
// http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-int.php
// inside your save_post/update_post hooks callback function,
// just type cast to float. You could also do a check if it contains non numeric chars
// and then simply return;
$check = ! is_float( $value ) OR ! is_int( $value ) ? new WP_Error( 'wrong value', __(" I've fallen and can't get up", 'YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN_STRING' ), $value ) : $value;
```

At the end of your function, check if you got an error. To provide a meaningful error message, use jQuery:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $check ) )
{
    $code = $check->get_error_code();
    $msg = $check->get_error_message();
    // Maybe multiple? You'll have to loop through them
    $msgs = $check->get_error_messages();

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
         var error = '<div id=\"message\" class=\"updated below-h2\"><p><strong>{$code}</strong> {$msg}</p></div>';
         // Append the error
         jQuery( '#icon-edit' ).after( error );
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Ok that's what i was looking for :)